# Give a time between tasks - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location, wait

I'm getting my location position from the iPhone's GPS. I want to get the coordinate from the same point 15 times (to get the best horizontal accuracy).

Is there a way to wait for example, 2 seconds between one coordinate and another?

I use an object called coordinate, with latitude and longitude as property.

```
.... Exemple code
Coordinate * coord = [[Coordinate alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (i=0 ; i<=14; i++)
{
    coord = newlocation;
    [coordinates addObject:coord];
    .... some code to wait 2 seconds before add a new object to the array....
}
```

I tried to use `NSThread sleepfortimeinterval`, but the view freezes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a `for` loop like this, you could theoretically use a repeating `NSTimer` that fired every two seconds, and then `invalidate` the timer after 15 iterations.

But I'd not suggest doing that, but rather shift to an event-driven model, waiting for calls to your `didUpdateLocations`. There's no point in checking in two seconds, if `didUpdateLocations` hasn't been updated. Likewise, there's no point in repeatedly checking 15 times over 30 seconds if, for example, you get a really accurate location after 5 seconds.

I'd suggest start monitoring the location, watch the locations as they come in with subsequent calls to `didUpdateLocations`, and examine `horizontalAccuracy` of the `CLLocation` (which tells you how accurate the location is). Once you reach the desired `horizontalAccuracy`, you can declare success (e.g. stop monitoring locations or whatever). You could also establish a `NSTimer` that automatically turned off the monitoring of locations after 30 seconds, if you want, as well.

---

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [self startStandardUpdates];

    // after 30 seconds, if we haven't found a location, declare success with whatever we got (if anything)

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(30.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self stopStandardUpdates];  // stop monitoring location if you want

        if (!self.foundLocation) {
            if (self.bestLocation) {
                NSLog(@"Didn't find perfect location, but location has accuracy of %.1f meters", self.bestLocation.horizontalAccuracy);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Even after 30 seconds, did not find any locations!");
            }
        }
    });
}

#pragma mark - Location Services

- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == self.locationManager)
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)stopStandardUpdates
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager = nil;
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"%s: horizontalAccuracy = %.1f", __FUNCTION__, location.horizontalAccuracy);

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0)  // not a valid location
        return;

    // this checks to see if the location is more accurate than the last;
    // or you might just want to eliminate this `if` clause, because if
    // you get updated location, you can probably assume it's better than
    // the last one (esp if the user might be moving)

    if (!self.bestLocation || location.horizontalAccuracy <= self.bestLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        self.bestLocation = location;
    }

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy <= 5) { // use whatever you want here
        NSLog(@"Found location %@", location);
        self.foundLocation = YES;
        [self stopStandardUpdates]; // stop it if you want
    }
}
```

This uses the following properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *bestLocation;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL foundLocation;
```

Comment: On my tests, standing on the same place, if i click twice the button to get location (secods between touchs), the `horizontal accuracy` and `location` changes due signal oscillation.  If i just stop monitoring locations, the app will take a long time to establish a good signal again.

Comment: @FelipeBoszczowski Fine, then don't turn off location services. But the idea is keep monitoring locations until (a) you get the desired accuracy; or (b) a certain amount of time has elapsed. But don't just iterating, keep checking locations, because you may have found a good location already, and if not, there's no point in checking again in a fixed amount of time, because there's no point in checking for another location before you get a call to your `didUpdateLocations`. See code sample in my revised answer as a suggestion. Change as you see fit, but this is example of event-driven approach.